# Crossfiltering of JSON data by the most recent time

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

Hi i was facing problem with filtering out the most recent data from my data file.
I have the following data

```
var data=
[
{"id":1,"speed":50,time:10:51.30},
{"id":1,"speed":40,time:10:51.40},
{"id":1,"speed":60,time:10:51.50},
{"id":1,"speed":55,time:10:51.55},
{"id":2,"speed":55,time:10:51.50},
{"id":2,"speed":65,time:10:51.58}
]
```

I want to filter out the data to visualize or show the data with most recent time. So my filtered data should contain the following

```
var filtereddata=
[
{"id":1,"speed":55,time:10:51.55},
{"id":2,"speed":65,time:10:51.58}
]
```

How can i get the filtered data from data using crossfilter?
I was trying with

```
var ndx=crossfilter(data);
var dim=ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.time;});
var filter=dim.filter(function(d){d3.max(data,function(d){return d.time;})});
```

But its not working? How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are looking at the filter object. You need to convert filtered dim to array using either top or bottom.

Please see the code below or better check out [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/r9jLakL9/1/) for the working version.

```
var data=[
{id:1,speed:50, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:00')},
{id:2,speed:40, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:10')},
{id:3,speed:60, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:20')},
{id:4,speed:51, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:30')},
{id:5,speed:55, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:40')},
{id:6,speed:65, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:50')}];




var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dataByTime = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.time;
});

var dataBySpeed = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.speed;
});

//var speedFilter = dataBySpeed.filter(function (d) {});

var timeFilter = dataByTime.filter(function(d){});

//console.log(speedFilter.filterRange([40, 55]).top(3));
console.log(timeFilter.filterRange([new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:00'), new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:40')]).top(3));
```

**______UPDATE_____**

OK I see what you meant. See below for updated code snippet. I also updated [solution at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9jLakL9/2/)

```
var data=[
{id:1,speed:50, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:00')},
{id:2,speed:40, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:10')},
{id:2,speed:60, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:20')},
{id:3,speed:51, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:30')},
{id:3,speed:55, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:40')},
{id:3,speed:65, time: new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:50')}];

var uniqueVals = new Map();
data.forEach(function(d){ 
    var existingVal = uniqueVals.get(d.id);
    if (existingVal){
        if (existingVal.time < d.time){
            uniqueVals.set(d.id, d);
        }
    } else {
        uniqueVals.set(d.id, d);
    }
    });

var finalData = [];
uniqueVals.forEach(function(d){ finalData.push(d); });
console.log(uniqueVals);
```

Comment: Your code is not serving my purpose. For your data i should get all row as output as there are no rows with duplicate id. For example if there were multiple rows for id:1 i would only take on row with the most recent time. That's my aim. Can you help regarding this?